# Need to hide Report Tab from opencart admin panel

Tags: report, admin, opencart-3

I need to remove the report tab from admin panel mentioned in attached image.

[OPEN CART ADMIN PANEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQNrT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it using CSS.
to file: `admin/view/stylesheet/stylesheet.css`
add:

```
li#menu-report {
    display: none;
}
```